# 日本語に誤り：削削除された最近の回答

Tags: バグ, 完了, 日本語

ユーザー → 回答 の最下段の日本語に誤りがあります。

> 削削除された最近の回答

正しくは下記であるべきです。

> 削除された最近の回答

Answer (score 1, accepted):

更新しました。次回のビルドに適用しますので、しばらくお待ちください。